# WCFData.Service1 Does not implement interface member

Tags: c#, wcf

I am following a guide on WCF on C# using visual studio 2010. I thought I was doing everything correct, till I built the solution and I am meet with this error. Can someone tell me what to do and how to fix it? Also why its happening? I am fairly new to this, so any help will be greatly appericated.

This is my code. The error appears in the first line, in `Service1 : IService1`. I do see the note but I tried changing service1 to say "Hello" but no luck.

```
namespace WCFData
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu
    // to change the class name "Service1" in both code
    // and config file together.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder;
        void ConnectToDB()
        {
            connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            connStringBuilder.DataSource = "NATHAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS";
            connStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = "WCF";
            connStringBuilder.Encrypt = true;
            connStringBuilder.TrustServerCertificate = true;
            connStringBuilder.ConnectTimeout = 30;
            connStringBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
            connStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

            conn = new SqlConnection(connStringBuilder.ToString());
            conn = conn.CreateCommand();


        }

        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }

        public int InsertPerson(Person p)
        {

            try
            {
                comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Person Values(@Id, @Name, @age)";
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", p.Id);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", p.Name);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("Age", p.Age);

                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                conn.Open();

                return comm.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to show us the `IService1` interface you wrote. The issue is due to the fact that you're not implementing its method(s)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click on the interface `IService1` and select "Implement Interface."

This will add the appropriate methods to your class.

Then check if you are misspelling their signatures in your code.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for that, fixed it, cant believe I missed that. However now I am getting this error.

http://imgur.com/a/1O6SN

Comment: What error are you getting now? Pls, consider also accepting this as answer for your original question. Thanks

Comment: it is var cmd = conn.CreateCommand(); etc... You have already created a connection, now you are creating a command from that connection

Comment: var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

Would this be it? Thanks for the help :)